# How can I swap or specify the position of legend elements?

Tags: r, legend, geom-col

No matter what I have tried, I can't seem to switch the positions of the two legend elements in my plot.

I need `Chats started` to appear first and `Chats completed` to appear next.

Here is the data frame:

```
grouped <- structure(list(date = c("2018-07-16", "2018-07-17", "2018-07-18", 
"2018-07-19", "2018-07-20", "2018-07-21", "2018-07-22", "2018-07-23", 
"2018-07-24", "2018-07-25", "2018-07-26", "2018-07-27", "2018-07-28", 
"2018-07-29", "2018-07-30", "2018-07-31"), homepage_opens = c(5L, 
0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    sitewide_opens = c(39L, 34L, 19L, 62L, 46L, 44L, 16L, 51L, 
    25L, 66L, 75L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), chats_started = c(10L, 
    16L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 5L, 13L, 4L, 8L, 11L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), chats_completed = c(7L, 13L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 6L, 
    13L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Here is the plot code:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(grouped) +
  geom_col(aes(x = date, y = chats_started, fill = "Chats started"),
           colour = "black",
           alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_col(aes(x = date, y = chats_completed, fill = "Chats completed"),
           colour = "black",
           alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(x = date, y = chats_started, label = chats_started),
            colour = "black",
            hjust = -0.15,
            vjust = -1.5,
            size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(x = date, y = chats_completed, label = chats_completed),
            hjust = -0.15,
            vjust = -1.5,
            size = 3,
            colour = "black") +
  labs(title = paste0("Chat Analysis\n(started vs. completed)"),
       x = "Date",
       y = "Count") +
  theme(legend.position = "top",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(colour = "black")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Chats completed" = "lightgreen", "Chats started" = "sandybrown"),
                    labels = c("Chats completed", "Chats started"))
```

And here is what I end up with:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)` as shown in the [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/#reversing-the-order-of-items-in-the-legend):

```
ggplot(grouped) +
    geom_col(aes(x = date, y = chats_started, fill = "Chats started"),
             colour = "black",
             alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_col(aes(x = date, y = chats_completed, fill = "Chats completed"),
             colour = "black",
             alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(x = date, y = chats_started, label = chats_started),
              colour = "black",
              hjust = -0.15,
              vjust = -1.5,
              size = 3) +
    geom_text(aes(x = date, y = chats_completed, label = chats_completed),
              hjust = -0.15,
              vjust = -1.5,
              size = 3,
              colour = "black") +
    labs(title = paste0("Chat Analysis\n(started vs. completed)"),
         x = "Date",
         y = "Count") +
    theme(legend.position = "top",
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text = element_text(colour = "black")) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Chats completed" = "lightgreen", "Chats started" = "sandybrown"),
                      labels = c("Chats completed", "Chats started"),
                      guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

[image]

For what it's worth, a search shows several different questions relating to legend ordering and various solutions to similar problems:

- [ggplot legends - change labels, order and title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075037/ggplot-legends-change-labels-order-and-title)
- [Legend ordering in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723317/legend-ordering-in-ggplot2)
- [How to reorder the items in a legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619402/how-to-reorder-the-items-in-a-legend)
- [How to reorder a legend in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26872905/how-to-reorder-a-legend-in-ggplot2)
- [Controlling ggplot2 legend display order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393123/controlling-ggplot2-legend-display-order)

However, none of the answers to these questions showed this simple solution to the specific problem of **reversing** the legend order, so I offer this answer rather than trying to judge whether one of the many questions out there are actually close enough to mark as a duplicate.