# Fail to change the order of legend items in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am practising R with open datasets, I gone through some questions online and see the following code can customise the order in legend, but it didn't work for me:

```
dataframe$column<-factor(dataframe$column, levels=c("b","g","e","y","k"))
```

So in this case, I want my order be: b,g,e,y,k instead of alphabetical order as default.

Here is the dataset:

```
mass<-c(0.187,0.257,0.237,0.064,0.047,0.191,0.080,0.155,0.229,0.258)
species<-c("B. constrictor", "B. constrictor", "B. constrictor", "M. nauta", 
"M. nauta","M. spilota","M. spilota","M. viridis","B. irregularis","B. 
irregularis")
mean<-c(11.02,17.05,12.80,1.53,0.78,6.52,1.66,5.93,10.37,11.67)
snake_info<-data.frame(species,mass,mean)
```

Here is my code I wrote:

```
snake_info$species<-factor(snake_info$species, 
levels=c("B.constrictor","M.nauta","M.spilota","M.viridis","B.irregularis"))
base_1a<-ggplot(snake_info, aes(x=mass, y=mean))+
geom_point(aes(shape=factor(species)))+
scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,15,17,25,2)) +
labs(x=expression(paste("mass"," ","(kg)")),y=expression(paste("total"," ",italic("F"),""[obs]," 
",italic("(N)"))))+
geom_smooth(method="lm", se = FALSE, col="black")+
theme_classic()
```

Unfortunately this is what I get - the order of legend is arranged alphabetically.
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Fa2.png)

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Is `snake_info` an open dataset that is available in R?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Legend ordering in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723317/legend-ordering-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Sorry guys for giving not enough information, I update the dataset above.

Comment: I tried the linked suggested, but after running the code the whole column of "species" wiped out, it became a column with nothing in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `levels` should match exactly with the `species` names present in the dataset. Here is the solution

```
library(tidyverse)

snake_info %>% 
  mutate(species=factor(species, levels=c("B. constrictor","M. nauta","M. spilota","M. viridis","B. irregularis"))) %>% 
           ggplot(aes(x=mass, y=mean), show.legend=FALSE) +
           geom_point(aes(shape=species)) +
           scale_shape_manual(values=c(1,15,17,25,2)) +
           labs(x=expression(paste("mass"," ","(kg)")),
           y=expression(paste("total"," ",italic("F"),""[obs]," ",italic("(N)"))))+
           geom_smooth(method="lm", se = FALSE, col="black") +
           theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!!   It works for me. I will try to figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: You have not provided space in `"B.constrictor", "M.nauta", "M.spilota", "M.viridis", "B.irregularis"` within `levels` function, but you data contains spaces between genus and species names like `"B. constrictor", "B. constrictor", ...`. As these two were not matching, the plot was coming empty.